# Chrome (Version 114.0.5735.198 ) show advanced settings

Tags: google-chrome, settings

In the my version of chrome (114.0.5735.198 ) I can't find the advanced setting?  Searching says "Alt-H" but macs don't have a ALT key. Neither cmd, opt or fn work.

If memory serves I used to go to settings in the ... menu and then select Advanced but that option no longer appears in the menu??

I even tried chrome://setting/advanced but that did not work.

I need to fiddle the TLS versions...

Comment: A quick Google search turned up this, "enter chrome://flags/" in the URL bar. There seems to be TLS settings there. Also Google says they don't hide "advanced" settings behind the `settings > advanced` selection any more...

Comment: Chrome on Mac actually [for a change] uses Apple's Toolbox standard to reach Settings, Cmd/, [comma] same as everything else. idk where TLS setting might be though. Possibly in flags? - `chrome://flags/`